Unable to migrate angular material 12 to 13
I'm struggling to upgrade Angular Material 12 to 13.
Issue:

Running ng serve gives me this error :
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Me\source\Workspaces\MyApp\@angular' at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2689:7) ...


What I'm doing that lead to this error:

Run ng update @angular/material@13 --allow-dirty --force

Here is package.json dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.4.0",
    "@lottiefiles/lottie-player": "^1.4.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^6.0.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "daisyui": "^1.16.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jsqr": "^1.4.0",
    "mat-select-filter": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-filesaver": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.47.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "three": "^0.153.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.29",
    "@types/three": "^0.152.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }

I already tried :

Deleting node_modules folder and run npm install

Update and solution:

Run npm uninstall @angular/material
Run ng add angular/material@13


When you deleted node_modules, did you also delete the package-lock.json file? And when you run npm install, do you get any errors or warnings? And if exists, can you also check your .browserslistrc file if you set there a fix version for a browser?

Did you check node version and compatibility with angular 13?
